# Which are the open sets? How about the closed sets?

Tags: general-topology, elementary-set-theory

Let $\mathbb{N}$ defined with the following topolog:
For every $A \subset \mathbb{N}$, $\bar{A} := \{kn; ~k \in \mathbb{N}, n \in A\}.$

So, I am being asked to describe how are the closed and the open sets. My attempt:

$A$ is closed if, and only if, $A = \bar{A}.$ It means that $A$ is closed if and only if $\forall n \in A, \{kn\}_{k \in \mathbb{N}} \subset A.$

So, $A$ is open if and only if there is $n \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $\{kn\}_{k\in \mathbb{N}} \not\subset A.$

Is this right?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: It is not right. Never assume that a set cannot be both open and closed.  Never assume that an open set does not have a non-empty closed set.  $N$ is open and $\{kn\}_{k\in N}= N$ when $k=1.$ Also,( for future consideration, not for what you said) never assume that if a set is not open then it  is closed,or vice-versa.

Comment: @user254665 thank you, I probably missed something, I know that I must not assume these kind of things, for construct the open sets I just tried to choose the complement, so the mistake is in the construction of closed sets; besides of I have used the negation wrong.

Comment: @user254665 could you write an answer explain what I did wrong? That's way I can improve myself. Even more, could you help me with the correct solution?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are more closed sets. You could have all the multiples of $2,3,$ or $5$ for example. The finite union of closed sets is closed.

For the open sets, You have two problems. First, to have a set not be closed, you just need one number to be missing, not all multiples. $\Bbb N \setminus \{6\}$ is not closed, but you ask for all multiples of $6$ to be deleted. That also makes a non-closed set. The second problem is that my example is not open because its complement is not closed.

Comment: So, how could you descibre the closed sets?

Comment: I would just say any subset of $\Bbb N$ and all multiples of the elements

Comment: look what I did: $\bar{A} = A\cup \mathbb{N}A$. Then, $A$ is closed if and only if $\bar{A} = A$, then, $A$ is closed if, and only if, $\mathbb{N}A \subset A.$

So, $A$ is open if and only if $A^c$ is closed. Then, $A$ is open if and only if $\mathbb{N}A^c \subset A^c$ and this, if and only if, $A \subset(\mathbb{N}A^c)^c.$

Answer (score 1):

It is the [lower topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Upper_topology) associated with the division order. The closed sets are the sets $S$ such that $s \in S$ and $s$ divides $t$ implies $t \in S$. Consequently, the open sets are the sets closed under division.

Comment: The first part is ok! Makes totaly sense. But, how could we be more specific? 

The open sets I don't get it, could you explain more?

Comment: Suppose $m,n$ belong to $S$ where $S$ is open and $m$ divides $ n. $ If $n/m \not \in S,$  then  $T= \overline { \{n/m\} }$ is a closed set disjoint from $S,$  But $n=(n/m)m\in \{(n/m)k\}_{k\in n} = \overline { \{n/m\} }= T,$  a contradiction.

Comment: @user254665 I know what I did wrong now! Thank you! But I still don't know how to solve...

Comment: @user254665 look what I am thinking in: $\bar{A} = A\cup \mathbb{N}A$. Then, $A$ is closed if and only if $\bar{A} = A$, then, $A$ is closed if, and only if, $\mathbb{N}A \subset A.$

So, $A$ is open if and only if $A^c$ is closed. Then, $A$ is open if and only if $\mathbb{N}A^c \subset A^c$ and this, if and only if, $A \subset(\mathbb{N}A^c)^c.$